# Javascript Code only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I am having some trouble getting my code to run on different browsers. I have written calculation code in javascript, however, this only work in Chrome, but not in some other browsers.

here is the screenshot with mozilla
[mozilla keep giving 1 value from the calculating result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivITG.jpg)

here is the screenshot with chrome
[with chrome it give a success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGLjj.jpg)

This is my form -

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'START_DATE', array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
            array(
                'name'=>'TrnProjectScheduleAct[START_DATE]',
                'id'=>'TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE',
                'value'=>$newformat = $model->START_DATE===NULL ? '' : date('d-M-Y', strtotime($model->START_DATE)),
                'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'fold', 
                'dateFormat' => 'dd-M-yy',
                'onSelect' => 'js:function(){
                    myUpdate(                                               
                        $("#TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE").val(),
                        $("#TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE").val(),
                        $("#TrnProjectScheduleAct_TOTAL")
                    );}',
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'style'=>'height:20px;', 'readonly'=>true
                ),
                )); 
                ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'START_DATE'); ?>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'END_DATE', array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
            array(
                'name'=>'TrnProjectScheduleAct[END_DATE]',
                'id'=>'TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE',
                'value'=>$newformat = $model->END_DATE===NULL ? '' : date('d-M-Y', strtotime($model->END_DATE)),
                'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'fold', 
                'dateFormat' => 'dd-M-yy',
                'onSelect' => 'js:function(){
                    myUpdate(                                               
                        $("#TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE").val(),
                        $("#TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE").val(),
                        $("#TrnProjectScheduleAct_TOTAL")
                    );}'
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'style'=>'height:20px;', 'readonly'=>true
                ),
                )); 
                ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'END_DATE'); ?>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'DAYS', array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'DAYS',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10, 'readonly'=>true, 'id'=>'TrnProjectScheduleAct_TOTAL')); echo "    Estimasi hari belum termasuk tanggal merah"; ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'DAYS'); ?>
</div>
```

this is the script

```
<script>
    $('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE, #TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE').change(function () {
            if ($('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE').is(":checked")) {
                $('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE').attr('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE').attr('disabled', false);
            }

            if ($('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_END_DATE').is(":checked")) {
                $('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE').attr('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $('#TrnProjectScheduleAct_START_DATE').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    function myUpdate(dt1, dt2,upd){
            var msec1 = dt1;            
            var date1 =  new Date(msec1);
            var msec2 = dt2;
            var date2 =  new Date(msec2);
            var diff = (isFinite(Math.round (date2 - date1) / 86400000) && Math.round (date2 - date1) / 86400000 || 0);
            var wEnd=0;

            if(date1>0 || date2>0){
                    for(var i=0; i<=diff; i++){
                        if(date1.getDay() ==6 || date1.getDay()==0){
                            wEnd = wEnd + 1;
                        }
                        date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                    }
                }
                upd.val(Math.round((diff-wEnd)+1));
            };
    </script>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here? 
Hope you can help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: please add a call of the function.

Comment: Just use some good tool that already does it clean: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: do you get erros in your console of your developer tools in say for example firefox?

Comment: Could you add an example of the function call so we can see the kind of parameters you're passing in?

Comment: Assuming you pass directly the other inputs' values as is, then yes, `"31-May-2017"` is not a valid date for FF (note that `"31 May 2017"` is).

Comment: i have edit my code, i display what value that i take n where i post them back after the script count

Comment: im using datepicker to fill the value tho

Comment: `empty string passed to getElementById()` said from the console @maunsinc

Comment: thankyou @Kaiido.. i just realize that it was my mistake. removing "-" solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's some different format in chrome and firefox format.
the problem is I'm using dd-mm-yyyy format. and it's only work at my chrome. when i remove "-", it works at both browser

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the day difference between 2 date object:

```
dayDiff = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 1000/60/60/24;
```

Comment: it didn't give a success